# How to automatically fill Excel/CSV cells without dragging

Tags: excel, csv, formatting, cell

I have a time-series dataset, including more than 200 countries and years between 2000 and 2021. My spreadsheet has three columns: Country, year, and value. I am trying to fill the country column without dragging the first item down. In each unit, the line starts with the country name, as you see in the photo. Ukraine -for instance- should be written next to all years. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6wvg.jpg)I have my country names which correspond to the year 2000. But, there should be country names for all the years between 2000 and 2021. I add a photo of my spreadsheet.

Comment: You can do this with formulas (using a helper column) or VBA. What have you tried and what problem did you encounter?

Comment: I would select all the cells needing that country, starting with the first cell having the name then click in the formula bar as if to edit contents and then ctrl+enter. Which will fill all selected cells but won’t change any formatting.

Comment: cybernetic.nomad I first used the series option in the home section. However, it did not work.

Comment: I found the "flash fill" option, but it only fills Ukraine when I choose necessary cells between 2000 and 2021.  It does not fill all the column automatically, which is a more useful way instead of dragging manually.